# How to clear the uppercase registers?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

The uppercase register has this nice characteristic of allowing appends to them.
However, every time I use them to yank a series of text, when it's time to paste them, I can see the old text from when I last used that same registry.

How can I clear them, prior to doing a series of yanks?

Comment: Hi @Guilherme, I try to close the question :-) Do you still have an aspect of your question that is not answered or could you accept the question using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mark it as done!

Comment: No problem :-) Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uppercase registers and the lowercase ones are actually the same.
When you yank using the lowercase version you replace the content of the register.  When you yank using the uppercase version you append the content to the register.

Hence the standard answer is: Don't clear the register just use the lowercase version for the first yank.

Otherwise you can use the following call to set the register 'A' to empty string:

```
:let @a=''
```

Or, alternatively (from @romainl)

```
qaq
```

Which starts recording the macro of register a (`qa`) and immediately stop recording (`q`), leaving it empty.

But to clear the 'A' register such that the `reg` command don't list it (following @filbranden) you can:

```
:call setreg('a', [])
```

Comment: In case it's not obvious to others how to clear a register from normal mode: `qaq` would clear the `a` register

Comment: `q<register>q` rolls better from the fingers.

Comment: ...which I first learned years ago from none other than @romainl!

Comment: You can use `:call setreg('a', [])` to actually *clear* the register itself (will no longer show in `:reg` output), rather than merely emptying it by setting it to an empty string.